# VBA Sort AlphaNumeric

Tags: vba, autocad

I have a function in VBA that is supposed to sort text based on a "Bubble sort".  If the text were just text then it would be fine, but my text is actually an alpha numeric string.  I tried to rewrite it to account for the number part but something is still off and I can't seem to figure out what. Please help!!

```
Dim alphaCurr As String
Dim alphaNext As String
Dim rowCurr As FsChartRow
Dim rowNext As FsChartRow
Dim c As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim vTemp As Variant

For c = 1 To rows.count - 1
    Set rowCurr = rows(c)
    alphaCurr = GetAlpha(rowCurr.label)
    For n = c + 1 To rows.count
        Set rowNext = rows(n)
        alphaNext = GetAlpha(rowNext.label)

        If alphaCurr > alphaNext Then
            Set vTemp = rows(n)
            rows.Remove n
            rows.Add vTemp, , c
        End If

    Next n
Next c

Dim numCurr As Integer
Dim numNext As Integer
Dim loopCount As Integer

    For c = 1 To rows.count - 1
        Set rowCurr = rows(c)
        alphaCurr = GetAlpha(rowCurr.label)
        numCurr = GetNumeric(rowCurr.label)
        For n = c + 1 To rows.count
            Set rowNext = rows(n)
            alphaNext = GetAlpha(rowNext.label)
            numNext = GetNumeric(rowNext.label)

            If alphaCurr = alphaNext Then
                If numCurr > numNext Then
                    Set vTemp = rows(n)
                    rows.Remove n
                    rows.Add vTemp, , c
                End If
            End If

        Next n
    Next c
```

The results I am getting are as follows:

"BK1"
"BK2"
"FB1"
"FB4"
"FB3"
"FB5"
"FB6"
"FB2"
"FJ2"
"FJ1"
"FJ3"
"FJ4"
"..."
"FJ15"
"RB1"
"H1"
"H2"

Thank for your help!

Comment: `I tried to rewrite it to account for the number part` - why simple buble sort doesn't suit?

Comment: Because it out putted the wrong order BK2 would be before BK1 etc...  Unless I was doing it wrong.  I followed an example I found on StackExchange.

Comment: you're doing something wrong..check [this](http://www.google.ru/url?q=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/830b42cf-8c97-4aaf-b34b-d860773281f7/sorting-an-array-in-vba-without-excel-function%3Fforum%3Disvvba&sa=U&ei=65ZZU8KOI8G34ATCg4Fw&ved=0CB0QFjAA&sig2=TTeYAD786rbpmyliPg27sg&usg=AFQjCNHk35L97w5XwaHdZ6UXIjbEv1uXfg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem.  I still could not get the bubble sort to work, so I created my own, that takes no more time to run then the bubble sort.  I'll post in case it helps anyone.

```
Private Function SortFsChartRow(collection As collection) As collection

Dim min As Integer
Dim max As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim rowCurr As FsChartRow
Dim numCurr As Integer
Dim rowMin As FsChartRow
Dim rowMax As FsChartRow

Dim search As Integer

Dim sorted As collection
Set sorted = New collection
min = 100
max = 0

For x = 1 To collection.count
    Set rowCurr = collection(x)
    numCurr = GetNumeric(rowCurr.label)
    If numCurr > max Then
        max = numCurr
        Set rowMax = rowCurr
    End If

    If numCurr < min Then
        min = numCurr
        Set rowMin = rowCurr
    End If
Next x

search = min

For y = 0 To max
    For x = 1 To collection.count
        Set rowCurr = collection(x)
        numCurr = GetNumeric(rowCurr.label)
        If numCurr = search Then
            sorted.Add rowCurr
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    search = search + 1
Next y

Set SortFsChartRow = sorted
```

End Function